# JUnit test web.xml with Spring MVC

Tags: testing, spring-mvc, junit, web.xml

**Does it exist a way to test the *web.xml* with JUnit in a Spring MVC application?**

I have a "web" folder at the root of my project. It contains a *WEB-INF/web.xml* file.

I write unit test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration("web")
@ContextConfiguration("path/to/mySpringApplicationContext.xml")
public class MyClassTest() extends AbstractMyClass {

   //...

   @Test
   public void testController(){
      mockMvc.perform(get("/path/to/myControllerURL"));
   }
 }
```

The *web.xml* is not read. I'm sure of that because when I do a syntax error in the web.xml file, the test still works.

Note: I could use an embedded Tomcat server to test the web.xml but I don't know if it exists a more simple way to test this file without an embedded server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing **integration test** of our code with spring framework. It does not include the java web container (usually tomcat or jetty), which are the ones concerned with `web.xml`. Please look at **functionnal testing** and tools like embedded jetty and [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) (these are not the only existing solutions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For functional testing:
1 - Could you advice me an easy-to-use library to call the exposed services?
2 - Is Selenium easy to use?
3 - Does it take a long time to implement functional tests? In a project, there is always the confrontation between developing quickly and creating tests (don't know if my explanation is clear...)

Comment: There is no magic solution, you need at least a web container (could be a embedded jetty launch by our test scripts or a tomcat running in our computer), script to automate the unloading and loading of our application in the container, then automaton to make action in the web container. Deploy this infrastructure in our project takes time but it worth it in long time.

Comment: Look a simple selenium + maven + spring integration example here: http://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/integration-test-a-web-application-with-selenium/

Comment: Of course but often, masterminds (e.g. salesman) don't see the added value on long-term... But this is another debate.

Comment: For small project, I don't use functional testing but when the project is a long-term project involving several developers, it is worth it.